# Windows compatibility: Permissions?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

OS Windows 10,
I am using Docker Engine version 18.09.2, the API version is 1.39

The website explaining the steps to run CAT is: https://libraries.io/pypi/medcat

I am building the medcat image locally. Output looks good until the end of the build process:

```
    Step 10/11 : ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 66b414e2093d
    Step 11/11 : CMD ["api.py"]
     ---> Using cache
     ---> db2acf6c4649
    Successfully built db2acf6c4649
    Successfully tagged cat:latest
    SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against 
    a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build 
    context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to 
    double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and 
    directories.
```

When I am trying to start the container I just built, I get:

```
    IT IS UMLS
     * Serving Flask app "api" (lazy loading)
     * Environment: production
       WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a 
    production deployment.
       Use a production WSGI server instead.
     * Debug mode: on
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "api.py", line 66, in <module>
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
    944, in run 
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", 
    line 1007, in run_simple
        run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, 
    reloader_type)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", 
    line 332, in run_with_reloader
        sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", 
    line 176, in restart_with_reloader
        exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, 
    close_fds=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in 
    _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/cat/api/api.py'
```

Does anyone have experience with building on Windows? Does the security warning have anything to do with this?

**Update:**
I added the permission for linux executable as in the received answer at this post. Then I built the image locally using the following command `docker build --network=host -t cat -f Dockerfile.MedMen .`, and the end of the building process gives me the same `Security Warning`.
Then I checked `docker run --env-file=./envs/env_medann ubuntu:18.04 env`, which gave me:

```
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    HOSTNAME=3d5fd66fadbe
    TYPE=UMLS
    DEBUG=False
    CNTX_SPAN=6
    CNTX_SPAN_SHORT=2
    MIN_CUI_COUNT=100
    MIN_CUI_COUNT_STRICT=1
    MIN_ACC=0.01
    MIN_CONCEPT_LENGTH=1
    NEG_PROB=0.2
    LBL_STYLE=def
    SPACY_MODEL=en_core_sci_md
    UMLS_MODEL=/cat/models/med_ann_norm.dat
    VOCAB_MODEL=/cat/models/med_ann_norm_dict.dat
    MKL_NUM_THREAD=1
    NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
    OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
    HOME=/root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>This is because windows & linux has `CR-LF` & `LF` difference issue, meanwhile, permission need to be added for linux executable.</del>

<del>For your case, as you have got the source code, I think you have git installed on your windows. Then, you can open `Git Bash`, change the path to your source code directory, and execute next in it:</del>



    <del>find . -type f | xargs dos2unix

    chmod -R 777 *</del>

<del>Finally, rebuild it.</del>

---

**Update:**

I try your code completely, it seems the issue is in `cat/api/api.py`, it misses a `#!`. So, into your sourcecode, edit `cat/api/api.py`, add next at the beginning of the sourcecode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then, rebuild with Dockerfile & run it again, you can see the effect from browser:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195241/discussion-on-answer-by-atline-windows-compatibility-permissions).